# Edit each line of text

Tags: text, vbscript, edit

I have a text file with 60k+ of directory lines. How can I edit each line to go from this:

```
C:\AJ\RPG Maker\Whisper of a Rose\OST\39 The Jewel (extended mix).mp3
```

To this:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\AJ\RPG Maker\Whisper of a Rose\OST" "E:\AJ\RPG Maker\Whisper of a Rose\OST" "39 The Jewel (extended mix).mp3"
```

I was thinking about a VBScript, but I can't get any further than this because I have no knowledge of it:

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "c:\file.txt"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If 
    End If 
    WScript.Echo strLine
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `FileSystemObject` doesn't allow for editing a file, create a separate file to contain your output:

```
Set objFile2 = objFS.CreateTextFile("c:\out.txt", True)
```

Then, using the loop you've already created:

```
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream

    strLine = objFile.ReadLine

    ' Get the parent folder and the file name...
    strFolder = objFS.GetParentFolderName(strLine)
    strFile   = objFS.GetFileName(strLine)

    ' Write the command to the new output file...
    objFile2.Write "ROBOCOPY "
    objFile2.Write Chr(34) & strFolder & Chr(34) & " "
    objFile2.Write Chr(34) & "E" & Mid(strFolder, 2) & Chr(34) & " "
    objFile2.Write Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34) & vbCrLf

Loop
```

Nothing too tricky here. Just extracting parts of the file name using methods provided by the `FileSystemObject` and then concatenating strings to create our output. `Chr(34)` is used to represent a quote character in your output file.

Comment: Oh my -- you're amazing! Thank you so much for this. :)

Comment: Sorry, quick follow-up: how can I use this script with a Unicode txt file? I have about 10k files that contain foreign characters (Chinese, Japanese, etc.) Running the script on a Unicode txt file results in this: ROBOCOPY "" "E" "ÿþC"

Comment: When you open your text file using [`OpenTextFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx) pass `TristateTrue` (value = `-1`) as the 4th parameter to open the file as Unicode.

Comment: Thank you, that makes the script run, but it crashes on the first line that contains Unicode when it tries to write it. On this line specifically:
`objFile2.Write Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34) & vbCrLf`
It crashes instead of writing the filename containing Chinese characters. I'm using this: `Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1, False, -1)` "Invalid procedure call or argument, line 17, char 5. Runtime error"

Comment: `Set objFile2 = objFS.CreateTextFile("c:\out.txt", True, True)` Seems to have fixed it. ^_^

Comment: Sorry, was late getting to your comment. Yes, your output file would need to be Unicode as well. Looks like you've figured that out.

Comment: No problem! Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, feel free to [upvote/accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).